# Como mudar o valor de uma variável do php utilizando JavaScript ou Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

**Contextualização**
Ao cadastrar um projeto por padrão (default) o **Status da Documentação**  é **pendente** em consequência desta configuração as **abas do projeto não são visíveis.** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Caso o usuário mude o **Status da Documentação** para **Autorizado** ou **Em conformidade** e pressione o botão **Autorizar Documentação** as **abas do projeto ficarão visíveis.** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dúvida:** Como fazer este evento em JavaScript, Ajax ou JQuery?

**Possível Solução:** Declarei a variável do php **$btnAutorizarDocumento** como do tipo **booleano**. Mas estou com dificuldade de fazer a lógica de programação. Pois quando esta variável for **"Autorizado"** ou **"Em Conformidade"** ela deve ser verdadeira, caso ao contrário deve ser falsa.

**Segue os códigos:**
O cadastro do projeto é feito no modo de edição.
Método de **editar** da classe **ProjetoController.php**:

```
 //Método que  redireciona para a página de editar o  Projeto
 public function edita($id, Request $request)
 {
    $btnAutorizarDocumento = false;
    $setores = Setor::all();
    $proponentes = Proponente::all(); 
    $tipoProjetos = TipoProjeto::all(); 
    $modalidadeApoios = ModalidadeApoio::all();
    $localidades = Localidade::all(); 
    $permissoesAprovacao = verificarPermissao('Aprovação');
    $permissoesJuridico = verificarPermissao('Juridico');
    $permissoesGestaoContrato = verificarPermissao('Gestão Contratos e Convênios');
    $permissoesFinanceiro = verificarPermissao('Financeiro');
    $permissoesOcorrencia = verificarPermissao('Ocorrência'); 
    $permissoesAbas= verificarPermissao('Abas do Projeto'); 
    $permissoesDadosGeraisProj= verificarPermissao('Dados Gerais do Projeto'); 
    $usuarioResponsavel = Auth::user()->name;

    return view('admin.projeto.edita', ['projeto' => Projeto::find($id), 'permissoesAprovacao' =>  $permissoesAprovacao, 'permissoesJuridico' => $permissoesJuridico,
            'permissoesGestaoContrato' =>  $permissoesGestaoContrato , 'permissoesFinanceiro' => $permissoesFinanceiro,
            'permissoesOcorrencia'=> $permissoesOcorrencia, 'permissoesDadosGeraisProj' => $permissoesDadosGeraisProj,
            'permissoesAbas' =>  $permissoesAbas, 'setores' => $setores, 'proponentes' => $proponentes, 'tipoProjetos' => $tipoProjetos,
            'localidades' => $localidades,'modalidadeApoios' => $modalidadeApoios, 'usuarioResponsavel'=>$usuarioResponsavel,'btnAutorizarDocumento' =>$btnAutorizarDocumento]);
 }
```

Trecho do código da página de edição do projeto **edita.blade.php**. Contém o **combo de seleção** e o botão **Autorizar Documentação**.

```
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Status da Documentação</label>
                <select multiple id="statusDoc" class="form-control" type="text" class="form-control" name="statusDoc" >
                    <option value="A" {{old('statusDoc') == 'A' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Autorizado</option>
                    <option value="P" {{old('statusDoc') == 'P' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Pendente</option>
                    <option value="C" {{old('statusDoc') == 'C' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Em Conformidade</option>
                </select>                
                </div>
 <button  id="btnAutorizarDocumento" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" 
                        align="center" style="width: 180px; height: 40px" onclick="click();">
                        Autorizar Documentação
                        </button>
```

**Trecho da  Condicional que valida a visibilidade das abas do projeto.**
Explicação: se o usuário tiver permissão para visualizar as abas e o documento for  autorizado as abas ficarão visíveis.

> @if($permissoesAbas->create == 1 && $btnAutorizarDocumento)

```
  <!--Inicio da abas-->
    @if($permissoesAbas->create == 1 && $btnAutorizarDocumento)

    <div class="card">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->

         <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist" >
            <li  class="nav-item nav-link active"  aria-controls="aprovacao" data-toggle="tab" href="#aprovacao" role="presentation" aria-selected="true"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Aprovação</a></li> 
            <li  role="presentation"><a href="#juridico" aria-controls="juridico"  data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i> Jurídico</a></li>
            <li  role="presentation"><a href="#gestaoContrato" aria-controls="gestaoContrato"  data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> Gestão de Contratos e Convênios</a></li>
            <li  role="presentation"><a href="#financeiro" aria-controls="financeiro"  data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i> Financeiro</a></li>
            <li  role="presentation"><a href="#ocorrencia" aria-controls="ocorrencia"  data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ocorrências</a></li>
          </ul>
```

**Trecho em JavaScript que fará este evento (arquivo edita.blade.php)**
Obs: está incompleto

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $( "#btnAutorizarDocumento" ).bind( "click", function() {
            $( "{$btnAutorizarDocumento}" ).val(true);
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Remova o `onclick="click();` do botão... o evento já é capturado no `bind`, senão o botão será clicado 2x.

Comment: Obrigada, eu fiz a modificação. Mas a minha dúvida principal é sobre a  lógica de programação que provavelmente será feita em JavaScript.

Comment: Pelo que entendi vc quer mudar uma variável PHP, não é isso? E está querendo usar Ajax para isso.

Comment: Sim. É isto, mas eu não sei como fazer esta modificação. Pois tenho pouco conhecimento em JavaScript e suas tecnologias.

Comment: o problema é que não tem como alterar uma variável PHP, a não ser session

Comment: Gostaria que você postasse um exemplo, para eu ter uma ideia de como solucionar isto.

Comment: Vc acha que enviando alguma "coisa" para uma página PHP via Ajax conseguiria alterar alguma coisa?

Comment: Um exemplo básico de Ajax: `var valor = "o que quero enviar para o PHP";
$.ajax({
   url: "pagina.php",
   type: 'POST',
   data: {valor:valor},
   success: function(data) {
      // data é o que retorna do servidor, se quiser que algo retorne
      // caso não deseje resposta, pode apagar este success: function(data){....}
   }
});`

Comment: Obrigada. Irei fazer os testes. :)

Comment: Neste caso, utilizando sessão. A variável do php dever ser do tipo session?

Comment: A variável pode pegar o valor da sessão: `$variavel = $_SESSION['nome_da_session'];`

Comment: Mas como eu disse, vc não consegue alterar variável PHP via Ajax... vc consegue alterar Sessão. Por exemplo, se `$_SESSION['nome_da_session'] = "1";`, com Ajax vc pode mudar o valor para `$_SESSION['nome_da_session'] = "2";`, por exemplo.

Comment: Boa tarde, @dvd. Eu postei outra dúvida referente a este problema. Eu tentei solucionar com o ajax; gostaria que vc me ajudasse. Segue o link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290916/como-sincronizar-o-ajax-com-o-php-para-manipular-os-dados