# No AJAX somente é executado o "Fail", como solucionar este problema?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

**Contextualização**

Quando o usuário pressionar o botão **Autorizar Documentação** será exibido o modal **Autorização** que pedirá para selecionar o usuário e digitar a senha, como é mostrado na imagem a seguir. 

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Regra de negócio**

Por **default** o status da documentação é **Pendente** ou **P**. Quando usuário preencher o "modal" de autorização, será validado se o usuário e a senha informada é igual ao do banco de dados. Em caso positivo o status da documentação é configurado para **"Autorizado ou A"** e este dados é salvo no banco de  dados. E os dados das abas são habilitados.

> Dados Desabilitados
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> Dados Habilitados (após pressionar o botão) 
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dúvida:**

Apesar do usuário e senha informado serem iguais ao do banco de dados é exibido o erro: **"Erro ao Autorizar Documentação"**. Referente ao arquivo **projeto-autorizaDocs**. Sempre é executado o método **fail** ao invés do **done**. Como solucionar este problema?

Método **autorizaDocumentacao** da classe **ProjetoController.php**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\User;
use App\Helpers\helpers;
use App\Models\Projeto;
use App\Models\Setor;
use App\Models\Proponente;
use App\Models\TipoProjeto;
use App\Models\Localidade;
use App\Models\ModalidadeApoio;
use App\Models\LocalidadeProjeto;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ProjetoController extends Controller
{
    private $projeto;
    private $novoProjeto;
    public  $autorizaDoc;//revisar a funcionalidade desta variável

    //Construtor do projeto
    public function __construct(Projeto $projeto)
     {
         $this->projeto = $projeto;  
         $this->autorizaDoc = false;  
     }

     //Redireciona os dados do projeto para a página principal
     public function index(Request $request)
     {
         $permissao = verificarPermissao('Projetos');
         $projetos = Projeto::all();
         return view('admin.projeto.index',['projetos' => $projetos, 'permissoesPerfil' => $permissao]); 
     }

    //Este método apresenta o formulário para cadastrar um novo projeto
    public function novo()
    {
        $this->autorizaDoc = false;
        $setores = Setor::all();
        $proponentes = Proponente::all(); 
        $tipoProjetos = TipoProjeto::all(); 
        $modalidadeApoios = ModalidadeApoio::all();
        $localidades = Localidade::all(); 
        $permissoesAprovacao = verificarPermissao('Aprovação');
        $permissoesJuridico = verificarPermissao('Juridico');
        $permissoesGestaoContrato = verificarPermissao('Gestão Contratos e Convênios');
        $permissoesFinanceiro = verificarPermissao('Financeiro');
        $permissoesOcorrencia = verificarPermissao('Ocorrência'); 
        $permissoesAbas= verificarPermissao('Abas do Projeto'); 
        $permissoesDadosGeraisProj= verificarPermissao('Dados Gerais do Projeto'); 

        return view('admin.projeto.novo',
        ['permissoesAprovacao' =>  $permissoesAprovacao, 'permissoesJuridico' => $permissoesJuridico,
        'permissoesGestaoContrato' =>  $permissoesGestaoContrato , 'permissoesFinanceiro' => $permissoesFinanceiro,
        'permissoesOcorrencia'=> $permissoesOcorrencia, 'permissoesDadosGeraisProj' => $permissoesDadosGeraisProj,
        'permissoesAbas' =>  $permissoesAbas, 'setores' => $setores, 'proponentes' => $proponentes, 'tipoProjetos' => $tipoProjetos,
        'localidades' => $localidades,'modalidadeApoios' => $modalidadeApoios, 'autorizaDoc' => $this->autorizaDoc
        ]);
    }

     //Método para a consulta dos projetos
     public function consulta(Request $request){

        $condicoes = [];

        if($request->nome != null){
            $condicoes[] = [DB::raw('upper(nome_projeto)'), 'like', DB::raw('upper("%'.$request->get('nomeProjeto').'%")')];
        }

        if($request->processo != null){
            $condicoes[] = [DB::raw('upper(tipo_processo)'), 'like', DB::raw('upper("%'.$request->get('processo').'%")')];
        }

        if($request->data_inicio != null){
            $condicoes[] = ['dt_inicio', '=', $request->input('dtInicio')];


        if($request->data_final != null){
            $condicoes[] = ['dt_fim', '=', $request->input('dtFim')];
        }

        $request->flash(['nome_projeto', 'tipo_processo', 'dt_inicio', 'dt_fim']);
        $projetos = Projeto::where($condicoes)->orderBy('nome_projeto')->get();
        $permissao = verificarPermissao('Projetos');
        return view('admin.projeto.index',['projetos' => $projetos, 'permissoesPerfil' => $permissao]); 
    }

    }


      //Método para cadastrar os dados gerais do projeto 
      public function cadastro(Request $request, Projeto $projeto)
      {
        $novoProjeto =  $projeto->salvar($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('projeto.edita', $novoProjeto->id)->with('success','Sucesso ao cadastrar');;
      }



       //Método que  redireciona para a página de editar o  Projeto
     public function edita($id, Request $request)
     {
        $this->autorizaDoc = false;
        $usuarios = User::where('autoriza', '=', 'S')->get();
        $setores = Setor::all();
        $proponentes = Proponente::all(); 
        $tipoProjetos = TipoProjeto::all(); 
        $modalidadeApoios = ModalidadeApoio::all();
        $localidades = Localidade::all(); 
        $localidadesAtivas = Localidade::where('ativo', '=', 'S')->orderBy('localidade', 'asc')->get(); 
        $permissoesAprovacao = verificarPermissao('Aprovação');
        $permissoesJuridico = verificarPermissao('Juridico');
        $permissoesGestaoContrato = verificarPermissao('Gestão Contratos e Convênios');
        $permissoesFinanceiro = verificarPermissao('Financeiro');
        $permissoesOcorrencia = verificarPermissao('Ocorrência'); 
        $permissoesAbas= verificarPermissao('Abas do Projeto'); 
        $permissoesDadosGeraisProj= verificarPermissao('Dados Gerais do Projeto'); 
        $usuarioResponsavel = Auth::user()->name;

        return view('admin.projeto.edita', ['projeto' => Projeto::find($id), 'permissoesAprovacao' =>  $permissoesAprovacao, 'permissoesJuridico' => $permissoesJuridico,
                'permissoesGestaoContrato' =>  $permissoesGestaoContrato , 'permissoesFinanceiro' => $permissoesFinanceiro,
                'permissoesOcorrencia'=> $permissoesOcorrencia, 'permissoesDadosGeraisProj' => $permissoesDadosGeraisProj,
                'permissoesAbas' =>  $permissoesAbas, 'setores' => $setores, 'proponentes' => $proponentes, 'tipoProjetos' => $tipoProjetos, 'usuarios' => $usuarios,
                'localidades' => $localidades,'modalidadeApoios' => $modalidadeApoios, 'usuarioResponsavel'=>$usuarioResponsavel, 'localidadesAtivas'=> $localidadesAtivas,
                'autorizaDoc' =>$this->autorizaDoc]);
     }

        //Método para atualizar o Projeto
      public function atualiza(Request $request)
      {
        $projeto = Projeto::findOrFail($request->get('id'));
        $projeto->tipo_processo = $request->get('tipoProcesso');
        $projeto->processo = $request->get('numProcesso');                      
        $projeto->dt_protocolo =  $request->get('dtProtocolo');   
        $projeto->setor_origem_id = $request->get('setor');  
        $projeto->proponente_id = $request->get('proponente'); 
        $projeto->nome_projeto = $request->get('nomeProjeto');
        $projeto->dt_inicio = $request->get('dtInicio');
        $projeto->dt_fim = $request->get('dtFim');
        $projeto->dias_intercalados = $request->get('diasIntercalados'); 
        $projeto->tipo_projeto_id = $request->get('tipoProjeto'); 
        $projeto->modalidade_apoio_id = $request->get('modalidadeApoio'); 
        $projeto->localidade_id = $request->get('localidade'); 
        $projeto->valor_solicitado = $request->get('vlSolicitado');
        $projeto->arquivo_fisico = $request->get('arquivo');
        $projeto->dt_lancamento = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $projeto->dt_alteracao = null;
        $projeto->usu_lancamento_id = auth()->user()->id; //recebe o id do usuário logado
        $projeto->usu_responsavel_id = auth()->user()->id; //recebe o id do usuário logado

        $response =  $projeto->alterar($projeto);  

          if($response['success'])
          {
              return redirect()
                        ->route('projeto.edita',$projeto->id) 
                        ->with('success',$response['message']);
          }else
          {
              return redirect()
                        ->back()
                        ->with('error',$response['message']); 

          }

      }

        //Método para autorizar a documentação do Projeto
        public function autorizaDocumentacao(Request $request)
        {
           $usuario = User::findOrFail($request->get('idUsuario'));
           $projeto = Projeto::findOrFail($request->get('numProjeto'));
           $statusDoc =  $request->get('statusDoc');
           // $statusDoc =  'A';
            $statusDoc == 'P' ? 'A' :'A'; //Validação: se o status for pendente configura para autorizado (A)

            //Se a senha informada for igual ao do banco de dados o documento é autorizado
            if($usuario->password == $request->get('senha')){
              $this->autorizaDoc = true;
              $projeto->status_documentacao = $statusDoc;
              $response = $projeto->save();
              if($response)
              {
                return response()
                 ->json(['success' => 'Sucesso ao Autorizar Documentação '], 200);  
              }
              else{
                return redirect()
                ->json(['error' => 'Erro ao Autorizar Documentação'], 500);     
              } 
            }
            else{
               return redirect()
                ->json(['error' => 'Senha Incorreta'], 500);        
            } 

        }

        //Finalizar o método
        public function cadastroLocalidadesAtivas(Request $request)
        {
            $novosLocalidades =  $projeto->salvar($request->get('numProjeto'),$request>get('localidadesAtivasSelect')) ;



        }
}
```

**Código em Ajax:  projeto-autorizaDocs.js**

```
  $(document).on('click', '#btnAutorizar', function () {
  $('#numProjeto').val($(this).data('numProjeto'));
  $('#statusDoc').val($(this).data('statusDoc'));
  $('#idUsuario').val($(this).data('idUsuario'));
  $('#senha').val($(this).data('senha'));
});

//Ajax para autorizar documentação , e atualizar a página após a ação
$('.autorizaDocumentacao').click(function () {
  var numProjeto = $('#numProjeto').val();
  var statusDoc = $('#statusDoc').val();
  var idUsuario = $('#idUsuario').val();
  var senha     = $('#senha').val();

  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  }); 

  $.ajax({
      url: "/projetos/autorizaDocumentacao",
     // url:  "http://localhost:8000/projetos/autorizaDocumentacao",
      type: "POST",
       data: {numProjeto:numProjeto,statusDoc:statusDoc,idUsuario:idUsuario, senha:senha},
     //data: "numProjeto=numProjeto&statusDoc=statusDoc&idUsuario=idUsuario&senha=senha",
      dataType: "html"
  }).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.success) {    
       $("#statusDoc").val( $('option:contains("Autorizado")').val() );// muda o status da documentação

       setTimeout(() => {
            alert ('Eu entrei aqui');
            window.location.reload();
        }, 4000);
      }
      else {
         alert(response.error);
      }   
  }).fail(function () {
     alert ("Erro ao autorizar documentação");

  });

  return false;
});
```

**Modal de Autorização: edita.blade.php**

```
<!--Inicio do modal de Autorizar Documentação--> 
<div class="modal fade modal-default" id="modalAutorizarDocs" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="examplePositionCenter"
   role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-center">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Autorização</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group col-md-18" style="text-align:center">
               <select class="form-control" name="idUsuario"  required>
                  <option value="">Usuário Autorização</option>
                  @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
                  <option value="{{$usuario->id}}" {{old('usuario') == $usuario->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$usuario->name}}</option>
                  @endforeach
               </select>
               <br/>
               <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha"  placeholder="Senha"/>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <center>
               <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary autorizaDocumento" data-dismiss="modal"  align="center" style="width: 300px; height: 40px">Autorizar</a>
            </center>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!--Fim do modal de Autorizar Documentação-->
```

**Condicional responsável por habilitar e desabilitar os dados das abas: edita.blade.php**

A flag **autorizaDoc** deve ser verdadeira para os dados serem habilitados **(página edita.blade.php)**, como mostra a imagem a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Aba Response**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Aba Headers**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Inclua esse método na pergunta : `$projeto->save();` ou melhor toda a classe `Projeto`

Comment: Bom dia, @Atila Silva. A classe foi incluída no corpo da pergunta, aguardo sua resposta. :)

Comment: Por que você não joga a responsabilidade de armazenar o objeto para o model ?

Comment: Boa tarde, os outros métodos a responsabilidade de armazenar o objeto está no model, com exceção do método "autorizaDocumentacao", pois ele somente irá atualizar no banco de dados o "status da documentação", o outro dado  "$autorizaDoc" será atualizado na tela.

Answer (score -1):

A comparação da senha deve ser feita com a função de criptografia. Segue o  método **autorizaDocumentação** da Classe **ProjetoController.php** atualizado. Por isso estava executando a função **fail** do ajax, pois as senhas estavam diferentes (a senha do banco era criptografada e a do formulário não tinha criptografia).

```
//Método para autorizar a documentação do Projeto
        public function autorizaDocumentacao(Request $request)
        {
            if (!$usuario = User::findOrFail($request->get('idUsuario')))
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Usuário não encontrado'], 404);

            if (!$projeto = Projeto::findOrFail($request->get('numProjeto')))
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Projeto não encontrado'], 404);

              $statusDoc =  $request->statusDoc;

            if (Hash::check($request->get('senha'), $usuario->password)){
                $this->autorizaDoc = true;
                $projeto->status_documentacao = $statusDoc; //muda o status da documentação para "A"
                $projeto->usu_autoriza_doc_id = $usuario->id;//id do usuário que autorizou a documentação
            // $usuarioAutorizaDocs = $usuario->name; // nome do usuário que autorizou a documentação
                $projeto->save();

                return response()
                        ->json(['success' => 'Sucesso ao Autorizar Documentação',
                                'autorizaDoc' =>  $this->autorizaDoc], 200); 
            } else {
                return response()
                            ->json(['error' => 'Senha Incorreta'], 422);
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta ver e tratar o erro retornado do fail, algo como:

```
  ...
  }).fail(function (e) {
     console.error(e);
     alert ("Erro ao autorizar documentação");
  });
```